# FluentValidation with IActionFilter in Asp.net Core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, fluentvalidation

I use latest FluentValidation.AspNetCore(8.0.0) and Asp.net core(2.1.0). I implemented `IActionFilter` like below.

```
public class MyActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        var a = context.ModelState.IsValid;
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var a = context.ModelState.IsValid;
    }
}
```

and my request model defined below.

```
public class Class1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Class1Validator : AbstractValidator<Class1>
{
    public Class1Validator()
    {
        RuleFor(w => w.Id).GreaterThan(2);
    }
}
```

Below is my action in controller.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get(Class1 c1)
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    [HttpPost, Route("post1")]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody]Class1 c1)
    {
        return Ok(c1);
    }
}
```

Below is my ConfigureServices in Startup

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc(opt =>
        {
            opt.Filters.Add<MyActionFilter>();
        })
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
        .AddFluentValidation(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Class1Validator>();
        });
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
        });
    }
```

When I post `/api/values/post1`, it returns `{"Id": ["'Id' must be greater than '2'."  ]}` directly without step into `OnActionExecuting` on `MyActionFilter`, how can I makes it step into 'MyActionFilter' as I want do some custom code.